# Releasing Trapped Vermin

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I recently started played Dwarf Fortress, and not knowing that it wouldn't catch normal animals I caught some vermin from the Kennel. Now I have some rats and stuff sitting around in an animal trap on a stockpile, and I want to get rid of them either just be gone to free up space or release them to do something.(Maybe someone wants a pet rat/hedgehog/roach?) I've been trying to, but I just can't figure out how to. Can anyone tell me how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you move caged beasts in Dwarf Fortress?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4605/how-do-you-move-caged-beasts-in-dwarf-fortress)

Comment: @tzenes agreed. the accepted answer to that question is what he needs to know.

Comment: I already tried that, but it's an animal trap not a cage. I can't connect a lever to it, and I can't build it to take it off the stockpile either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [tame the small animal at the kennel](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php?title=DF2010:Kennel&section=5), and then they can be used as [pets](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Pet).  Some pets have a high value and can be used to make <s>useless dwarves</s> nobles happy.

To release the (now tame) animal use <kbd>q</kbd> to query the cage, <kbd>a</kbd> to assign, and then use enter  to toggle the animal(s) currently inside (animals assigned to the cage will have a green `+` next to them). Any available dwarf will perform the job. ([Source](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Cage))

Comment: Yeah, I have them tamed, but I thought they couldn't be adopted as pets until they're released...

Comment: @Ullallullo I corrected my answer, I thought taming automatically released them, but I see otherwise.

Comment: Yep, thanks. I figured that out about the time of your edit when I was setting my jail up.

Comment: Pet roach... make me happy to.

Comment: So, I've got the exact same problem. A bunch of traps (NOT CAGES) with tame vermin in them.  I still can't figure out how to get them out.  I don't want to make them pets, I just want them out of those traps for reuse.  Help?